# Blender 3.2 doesn't open because of an Addon

Tags: add-on, modular-tree-addon

I have been working with Blender 3.0 without problems and tried to download a newer Blender version (3.2) on my MacBook (MacBook Air, M1, Ventura 13.0.1) but it wouldn't open, just bounce in the dock, but it wouldn't react. Then I downloaded the old version again, but now it wouldn't open aswell. After some research online, I typed in

`"/Applications/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender"`

in the terminal, which led me to following answer:

```
"Read prefs: /Users/jenny/Library/Application Support/Blender/3.3/config/userpref.blend
addon not loaded: 'modular_tree'
cause: cannot import name 'm_tree' from partially initialized module 'modular_tree' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/jenny/Library/Application Support/Blender/3.3/scripts/addons/modular_tree/__init__.py)"
```

so I guess the problem lies in the Addon I installed for the older version (3.0) but I cannot figure out a way to solve this problem, maybe anyone in here can help me out what further steps I have to take to make Blender work again?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Go to `/Users/jenny/Library/Application Support/Blender/3.3/scripts/`and completely remove the `modular_tree/` folder

Comment: Thank you so much for answering so quickly! Unfortunately  I don't have the "Blender" folder in my Application Support, so I can't remove the folder. But I figured out, that if I download the 2.8 version, I at least can open Blender again! I now unchecked the modular_tree add-on in the preferences, and will try to install a newer version of blender, and then again install the add on, maybe this will work, I'll try tomorrow. Thank you again for the fast reply!

Comment: All you should need to do is delete the user preferences folder or `startup.blend` and it should work again, no need to re-install or download different versions. Different Blender versions use different preferences folders anyway, disabling it in 2.8 should have no effect for newer versions

Comment: Hi Jenny, the Library folder on MacOs in the finder is normally hidden. So try pressing "command" + "shift" + "." then you should see the folder.

Comment: Oh wow I found it! Thank you Chris, this saved me

Comment: Now I got a new problem, blender doesn't open again. When I try to open it, it only bounces in the dock. When I type in the command for opening blender in the terminal, I don't even get an error specification anymore, it just tries to open it the whole time...